# RDCOMClient log file

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I have been using RDCOMClient for a while now to interact with vendor software.  For the most part it has worked fine.  Recently, however, I have the need to loop through many operations (several hundred).  I am running into problems with the RDCOM.err file growing to a very large size (easily GBs).  This file is put in C: with no apparent option to change that.  Is there some way that I can suppress this output or specify another location for the file to go?  I don't need any of the output in the file so suppressing it would be best.

EDIT:  I tried to add to my script a `file.remove` but R has the file locked.  The only way I can get the lock released is to restart R.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the permissions to read only was going to be my suggested hack.
A slightly more elegant approach is to edit one line of the C code in  the package in src/RUtils.h from

`\#define errorLog(a,...)  fprintf(getErrorFILE(), a, ##__VA_ARGS__); fflush(getErrorFILE());`

to

`\#define errorLog(a, ...) {}`

However, I've pushed some simple updates to the package on github that add a writeErrors() function that one can use to toggle whether errors are written or not.  So this allows this to be turned on and off dynamically.
So

  `library(RDCOMClient)
  writeErrors(FALSE)`

will turn off the error logging to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this.  I created the files C:\RDCOM.err and C:\RDCOM_server.err and marked them both as read-only.  I am not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this, but for now I am running without logging.